# ng-bootstrap [ngb-tab] in Angular 4 styles issue

Tags: angular, tabs, bootstrap-tabs

Both tabs looks inactive after page loaded. Also if click anywhere - active tab styles became inactive, logic works but styles not. Works only hover styles

```
<ngb-tabset type="pills">
    <ngb-tab id="tab-1" title="Overview">


     <ng-template ngbTabContent>
              <div class="data-1"></div>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab id="tab-2" title="Overview">
         <ng-template ngbTabContent>
              <div class="data-2"></div>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

[image]